# Adding constraints crashes app

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I ve got a custom UIView which i load on my ViewController.

```
 func loadBottomSheet(){

        bottomSheet = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BottomSheetTest", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! BottomSheetTest
        bottomSheet?.setUp(parentController: self)
        bottomSheet?.tag = 9009164
        self.view.addSubview(bottomSheet!)
    }
```

The code for the custom view is the following:

```
 func setUp(parentController: UIViewController){

        self.parentController = parentController;

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentController.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentController.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(400)).isActive = true
        self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentController.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


    }
```

Im trying to add it to my view controller. The following code crashes the app with a generic error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

At this point i ve removed EVERYTHING from the custom view. What you see here is all there is to it, no more UI elements, no IBOutlets, this is it. Im at my wit's end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are adding constraint for a view that is not in your view hierarchy, so you first need add your desired view as subview and after that you can setup your constraints without a crash in the process

**You need move this line**

```
self.view.addSubview(bottomSheet!)
```

**above this one**

```
bottomSheet?.setUp(parentController: self)
```